# I'm not sure how to get the program to perform the calculation early?

Tags: python

I'm working my way through a python book and on of the problems it presented me was to take some code I made earlier for a gradebook calculator and make it so that the grade can be calculated earlier by user input. I decided to do this using an if statement that if input == -1 it should print the grade but it's not working right and I'm not sure what I did wrong. heres what i have right now.

I didn't think I was being clear enough about my issue. I was trying to get the program to stop after I entered a grade and make the calculation. Right now I have to put in all 5 grades before it will calculate the average grade but I'm trying to get it so that it'll calculate after putting in any number of grades. However I can't figure out what to do to make that work. Also I looked at my code and realized I could streamline it if I used arrays and an input system so i changed it to this now.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
print("Please enter the number of grades you wish to enter:")
number = int(input())
gradearray = []
for i in range(0, number):
    print("Please enter a grade")
    grade = float(input())
    gradearray.append(grade)
    if (grade > 90):
        print("You got an A!")
    elif (grade > 80):
        print("You got a B!")
    elif (grade > 70):
        print("You got a C!")
    elif (grade > 60):
        print("You got a D!")
    else:
        print("You got an F")
print("The average grade is:", sum(gradearray)/len(gradearray))
```

Comment: What is `input` in `input == -1` do you think ?

Comment: 1. Your indentation is incorrect (please provide a [MCVE]) 2. What is not working?

Comment: as azro pointed out, `input` doesn't make sense in that check. it's a function and will never be equal to `-1`. You want to check if `score` is equal to `-1`, no?

Comment: Functions should be defined at the global scope, generally. The `if __name__` block should only govern the behavior of your Python file if run as a standalone script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I was able to figure it out in an interesting way. by creating a new variable i was able to get it to work heres the revised code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
print("Please enter the number of grades you wish to enter:")
number = int(input())
gradearray = []
try:
    for i in range(0, number):
        print("Please enter a grade")
        grade = float(input())
        gradearray.append(grade)
        stop = float(input())
        if stop < 0:
            print("The average grade is:", sum(gradearray)/len(gradearray))
        if grade > 90:
            print("You got an A!")
        elif grade > 80:
            print("You got a B!")
        elif grade > 70:
            print("You got a C!")
        elif grade > 60:
            print("You got a D!")
        elif 0 < grade < 60:
            print("You got an F")
    print("The average grade is:", sum(gradearray)/len(gradearray))
except:
    print("cannot divide by 0")
```

basically it asks for two inputs now one for the grade and one to confirm if it's the last input. I also added error checking for a divide by 0 error

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague please describe in detail what you exactly want your code to do.

press ctrl-d to calculate and quit early.

```py
def calc_average(total):
    return total / 5

def determine_score(grade):
    if 90 <= grade <= 100: return 'A'
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:return 'B'
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79: return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69: return 'D'
    else: return 'F'

def calc_total(scores):
    total = sum(scores)
    avg = calc_average(total)
    grade = determine_score(avg)
    print(f"\nAverage grade is: {avg}")
    print(f"That's a(n): {grade}")


scores = []
students = 6

for i in range(students):
    try:
        score = int(input(f"Enter score {i}: "))
        print(f"That's a(n): {determine_score(score)}")
        scores.append(score)
    except EOFError:
        calc_total(scores)
        break

calc_total(scores)
```

Comment: basically I'm trying to get the code to interpret an input of -1 when the code is running as a command to calculate the score there instead of it requiring me to input all 5 scores before making the calculation

Comment: so you want to calculate the scores before you finish inputting all 5 scores?

Comment: yes That's what I'm trying to get it to do

Comment: ok check my answer i just edited it, please let me know if my code is correct.

Comment: ok so I ran it but the issue is that it didn't actually print anything off and only gave me exit code 0 when it ran.